# jQuery how to $.map over a dynamic length of an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have the following:

```
transformResult: function(response) {
  if (response && response.buckets && response.buckets[0] && response.buckets[0].documents) {
    return {
        suggestions: $.map(response.buckets[0].documents, function(dataItem) {
          return { value: dataItem._id, data: {
            key: response.buckets[0].key,
            url: dataItem.url
           }
          };
        })
    };

  }
```

I'm using `response.buckets[0]` to ensure at least one bucket exists in the array. There can be 0 or 1+ buckets. The problem is, now the suggestions are just returning for the first bucket w [0] in `response.buckets[0].documents`

How can I get the suggestions to return for 0 or more `$.map(response.buckets[0].documents`?

### Update

```
transformResult: function(response) {
  var suggestions = {
    suggestions: {}
  };

  if(!response || !response.buckets) {
    return suggestions;
  }

  for(var i=0;i<response.buckets.length;i++) {
    var bucket = response.buckets[i];
    if(!!bucket.documents) {

      suggestions.concat($.map(bucket.documents, function(item) {
            return {
              value: item._id,
              data: {
                key: bucket.key,
                url: item.url
              }
            }
      }));



    };
  }

  return suggestions;

},
```

This is now erroring with: `Uncaught TypeError: suggestions.concat is not a function`

Comment: Why don't you check for `length`: `response.buckets.length`???

Comment: @user2181397 No, it will throw an error if `response.buckets[0]` is undefined

Comment: first: `var suggestions` should be `{ suggestions: [] }`, second: Array.concat returns a new Array containing the result, it doesn't change the current Array. So you actually have to write `suggestions.suggestions = suggestions.suggestions.concat(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure wether I got your intention and data-structure right, but I think you're looking for this:

```
transformResult: function(response) {
    //seems that $.map() doesn't handle null-values :( 
    //so I have to take care of this
    var emptyArray = [];
    return {
        suggestions: $.map(response && response.buckets || emptyArray, function(bucket){
            //jQuerys map-implementation is actually more like a fmap.
            //so this doesn't return an Array of Arrays, but one flat Array instead
            return $.map(bucket.documents || emptyArray, function(document){
                return { 
                    value: document._id, 
                    data: {
                        key: bucket.key,
                        url: document.url
                    }
                }
            });
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you run a `for` loop on the `buckets`-array and inside the `for` run the `map` function on each element you should achieve what you are after.

```
var suggestions = [];
if(!response || !response.buckets) {
    return { suggestions: suggestions };
}
for(var i=0;i<response.buckets.length;i++) {
    var bucket = response.buckets[i];
    if(!!bucket.documents) {
        suggestions.concat($.map(bucket.documents, function(item) {
            return {
                value: item._id,
                data: {
                    key: bucket.key,
                    url: item.url
                }
            };
        }));
    }    
}
return { suggestions: suggestions };
```

If there are 0 buckets, the for-loop will not loop at all and the suggestions array will be of 0 length.

Comment: You also need to check that the `buckets` property exists on the `response`, as the OPs code does. It implies it can be `null`, which means calling the `length` property on `null` will throw an error

Comment: suggestions = [] isn't working, it has to be in this format:       var suggestions = {
        suggestions: {}
      };

updated code above.

Comment: Missed that too, wow I'm a bad question reader today! hehe. Fixed ;)

Comment: fyi, latest update errors w `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Comment: caught the typo. fyi, it isn't returning anything. I logged before the last return statement and now everything is console.logging []

Comment: ah come on @AnApprentice surely you can debug a syntax error in your ide